# Cordova installation issue on mac

Tags: node.js, cordova, proxy

I am facing a problem while installing Cordova on my iMac with the following errors.Kindly help:

> npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" npm ERR! node v6.11.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! errno
>   ENOTFOUND npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo  npm ERR! network getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443 npm ERR! network
>   This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! network and
>   is related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you
>   are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network  npm
>   ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm
>   ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config' 
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/Ameya/npm-debug.log

Comment: Error says that you're behind a corporate proxy/firewall which prevents you from installing the `cordova` library.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue myself when I was building an Ionic application. Can you try to uninstall npm and cordova entirely, and then reinstall it?

I got it working by doing that. Hopefully it worked for you.

Comment: Sorry, it's late. Let me clarify. It does make sense as an answer, but I think it could be improved if you rephrase as an answer instead of asking questions.

Comment: Well, it would be more of an "try it out if it works" kind of solution. Because that was exactly how I solved mine. I can't go into details and say what line is causing what issue. Hah.

Answer (score 0):

Download Nodejs for MAC from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Then use: sudo npm install -g npm-install